# “Operations to consider”(ex. If, return, assign..) when calculating time complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I’m studying algorithm - time complexity and recursion.
I’m actually ok with solving recursion, cuz it’s simple math. But code part is the problem.

For example, This is the problem I’ve brought :
https://brilliant.org/practice/big-o-notation/?problem=complexityrun-time-analysis-2-2

```
public int P(int x , int n){
    if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    if (n % 2 == 1){
        int y = P(x, (n - 1) / 2);
        return x * y * y;
    }
    else{
        int y = P(x, n / 2);
        return y * y;               
    }
}
```

It is a simple power function. T(n)=O(g(n)) is running time of this function for large, and I have to find it.

The solution says,
“When the power is odd an extra multiplication operation is performed. To work out time complexity, let us first look at the worst scenario, meaning let us assume that one additional multiplication operation is needed.”

However, I do not understand the next part, the solution says that :
**Recursion relation is**

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 3, T(1)=1
```

1) **Why is the constant part 3?**

```
if (n % 2 == 1){
        int y = P(x, (n - 1) / 2);
        return x * y * y;
    }
```

2) *I actually don’t get exactly why T(1)=1 also.* 
I’m puzzled with.. **which operations should we consider while calculating time complexity?**

For example, T(1)=1 part must be related with

```
if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
if (n % 2 == 1){
        int y = P(x, (n - 1) / 2);
        return x * y * y;
    }
```

This part, and *I want to ask whether T(1)=1 comes from if statement/assign statement/return statement..*

I understand afterwards, solving the recursion relation above, but I’m stuck with the recursion relation itself.

**Please help me algo guru**s..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which operations should we consider while calculating time complexity?

The answer will disappoint you a bit: it doesn't matter what operations you count. That's why we use big-Oh in analysing algorithms and expressing their time/memory requirements. It is an asymptotic notation that describes what happens to the algorithm for large values of n. By the definition of Big-Oh, we can say that both 1/2n^2 and 10n^2+6n+100 are O(n^2), even if they are not the same function. Counting all the operations, will just increase some constant factors, and that's why it doesn't really matter which ones you count.

By the above, the constants are simply O(1). This disregards details, since both 10 and 10000 are O(1), for example.

One could argue that specifying the exact number of operations in the expression `T(n) = T(n/2) + 3` is not very correct, since there is no definition for what an operation is, and moreover the same operation might take a different amount of time on different computers, so exactly counting the number of operations is a bit meaningless at best and simply wrong at worst. A better way of saying it is `T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)`.

`T(1)=1` represents the base case, which is solved in constant time (read: a constant number of operations at each time). Again, a better (more formal) way of saying that is `T(1)=O(1)`.